# TextArea does not handle MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED

Tags: css, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am building a `JavaFX` application and I have a `TextArea` inserted.
The `TextArea` has a `CSS` class assigned (don't know if it matters):

```
.default-cursor{
    -fx-background-color:#EEEEEE;
    -fx-cursor:default;
}
```

There are 2 issues about this `TextArea`:

1. `-fx-cursor:default;` Has no effect as the cursor remains the text cursor. That is weird as i use the same class for a `TextField` with proper/expected results
2. The TextArea does not handle `MOUSE_PRESSED` event
   My code is :

```
    textArea.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("print message");
                }
            });
```

Any ideas why?
I want to note that when I changed `EventHandler` to handle `MOUSE_CLICKED` everything is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the default handlers for mouse events on the TextArea are consuming the mouse pressed event before it gets to your handler.

Install an EventFilter instead:

```
textArea.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("mouse pressed");
            }
        });
```

The Event filter will get processed before the default handlers see the event.

For your css issue, try

```
.default-cursor .content {
  -fx-cursor: default ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work.
But do you know WHY? 
Your css solution works for TextArea but not for TextField.
And the EventFilter solution is a work-around and does not explain why.
But thanks :)

Comment: For the css, see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea). The content of the text area is placed in a scroll pane, and the cursor is set on the content of the scroll pane (so that you see a default cursor on the scroll bars, I assume). Since the content of the scroll pane is deeper in the scene graph than the text area itself, setting the cursor on the text area won't make any difference. And of course TextFields don't have scroll panes.

Comment: For the events, just as I explained it. The text area has to process mouse events in order to handle selection, etc. For reasons that are not clear to me, it is consuming those events. Since [handlers registered at the same level are executed in arbitrary order,](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD) you don't control whether or not your handler gets the event before the TextArea consumes it (and apparently, you get it after). The event filter will always receive it before the handler.