# Why is Mouse Pressed Event not working in TextArea of JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

This is my code:

```
@FXML private TextArea txtconfig;
public void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        txtconfig.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("PRESSED");
            }
        });
    }
```

In FXML:

```
TextArea fx:id="txtconfig"  style="-fx-font-size:10pt; -fx-font-family:Consolas"
              maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"
              onMousePressed="#handleMousePressed"/>
```

However, setOnMouseClicked is working keeping everything same. Only, onMousePressed is changed to onMouseClicked in FXML.

```
public void handleMouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        txtconfig.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                 System.out.println("Clicked");
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Both of these are wrong: you are setting the event handler in the event handler. So even in your "mouse clicked" version, you should only see the message the second and subsequent times you click in the text area. I think the reason the mouse pressed handler doesn't work at all is that the text area consumes mouse pressed events for some reason. Why are you registering low-level mouse event handlers with a text area anyway? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get caret position of the selected text in the TextArea from the point of Mouse Pressed to Mouse Released. And yes you are right about mouse clicked version. Is this code redundant? `txtconfig.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            }
        });`

Comment: Yes, that code is redundant. But why don't you simply register listeners with the [`selectionProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectionProperty) or the [`caretPositionProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#caretPositionProperty) (depending on exactly what you want to do), instead of messing with mouse events? (For one thing, your code has no chance of doing anything at all if the user selects text with the keyboard.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this later. And if you don't mind can you point me to some good resources for JavaFX with FXML. I went through Orcale's docs about FXML but it feels underwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348152/textarea-does-not-handle-mouseevent-mouse-pressed) you could install an `ÈventFilter` if you really need the `MousePressed` event (which seems to be consumed by the control itself):

```
txtconfig.addEventFilter(
    MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("PRESSED");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but I was setting the event handler in the event handler as told by @James_D in the comment so, it was not working. I removed the onMousePressed from FXML and added the EventFilter in the initialize() method and it worked. Please mention this in your answer for future reference.